# How do I make this link to open on same window and not safari [iPhone webapp]

Tags: html, iphone, web-applications, href

```
<style type="text/css">

        html, body {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    font-family:"helvetica";
    margin: 0;
}

       #picture  {position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       right:0px;
       height: 60px;
       width: 60px;}
}
    </style>
```

```
<A HREF="http://www.site.com/cool/somthing.html"><img src="teddy.png" alt="Small Image" id="picture"></a>
```

What are i doing wrong?
How do i make it so it opens on the same paga and dont start safari?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing nothing wrong. All external hyperlinks will cause Mobile Safari to launch, no matter what. You can't change that in your web app.

Internal links can remain in your web app if you stick to Ajax calls, but due to the same-origin policy you cannot use Ajax to open external sites.

Comment: There's the possibility, though, of using a server-side script (such as PHP with cURL?) to retrieve the external web sites and work around the same-origin policy?

Comment: @David Thomas: Hmmm, I'm not too sure, although I know that's possible with `UIWebView` for a native app. I don't know how far one could go with an HTML web app alone.

Comment: @BoltClock, I must confess that I hadn't really thought through the limitations of the iPhone aspect. But it seemed a worthwhile mention =)

Comment: @user558773: If it's your own site, then you can. You need to pick up JavaScript and Ajax, and modify your web app to use only Ajax to request your pages so Mobile Safari doesn't launch.